# Rails Browser Syntax Highlighting Plugin?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plugins, syntax-highlighting

What is the standard Rails plugin for syntax highlighting (in a website admin panel for example, not for TextMate) that works right out of the box in a Rails project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen many different ways for code highlighting in the Rails community.

- The GitHub crew loves [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). They are using it on many different places, including Jekyll and GitHub itself. The downside is that it's a python library so you would need to install python and execute it as a shell task.
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) is an other popular, JavaScript based solutions. This is the one adopted by WordPress and Yahoo! There are many different Rails plugins for this even if the integration doesn't actually require a plugin.
- Ruby offers 3 code highlighting Gems: [Ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/), [Syntax](http://rubyforge.org/projects/syntax) and [CodeRay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/). AFAIK, the last one is the most adopted.

I tried all those solutions in the past. I'm actually using Pygments for a couple of Jekyll blogs and JavaScript based solutions in all the other cases.

Comment: One downside to the client side based ones is the page loads first with no highlighting, then flips over after a second or so. Minor but distracting/annoying.  Haven't seen a way around this.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/). Not quite a plugin, but still very straight forward to integrate with Rails.

Answer (score 2):

We use highlight.js on http://giantrobots.thoughtbot.com (isn't a Rails app, but whatever), and it's awesome.

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/